# Communication between independant war projects on the same server

Tags: jakarta-ee, war

I am setting up an independant modules architecture where i can deploy war projects indepently.

So I can deploy & undeploy war projects that has nothing in common.

Is there any way for a war project (in a EJB or CDI Bean for example) to know that another war project is deployed on the same server ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is a target runtime (application server) for your web modules?

Comment: I'm using Glassfish atm but I would like to be able to use others servers

Comment: What do you know about WAR project you need to check if it exists? Is this information becomes available only at the runtime?

Comment: If I have 2 indepent war projects project-a-war & project-b-war, I want a root project running on my server accessible by the two others, that can check if project-a-war in running on the server and if project-b-war is running on the server.

Comment: The straightforward way is to initialize a JNDI-lookup on these two WARs from the root project and catch the NameNotFoundException. Surely it will work only in case of you know these JNDI names. It is not a brilliant approach to handle it that way, but it should work.

Comment: how you would do to adapt a menu interface of the projects deployed, then ?

Comment: Are you talking about GUI?

Comment: yes, i do want a list of deployed projects on my GUI, to do it, i need to be able to get a list of the deployed projects in a java bean for example.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/Context.html#list-java.lang.String-